# Building a SaaS product with Node + Express + Sequelize + (Mysql or Postgres)

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, saas

We are planning to build a SaaS based product, so mainly after a lot of search, we found there are three database approach for designing a SaaS product.

1. Separate database for each tenant
2. Separate schemas for each tenant
3. Shared schema and one databases for all tenants(But will query using tenant_id)

So we are planning to get into option 2,

So initially we use Mysql, but we did not found how to get multiple schemas in mysql, we are using **Sequelize** as ORM.

After a lot of googling, we found many **Multi tenant** based product is using postgresql for the powerful schema approach, So we tried this library:

https://github.com/westmark/sequelize-multi-tenant-enhancer

We tried this library for multiple schema based approach, but the data are 
not showing according to the tenant, Also i opened a issue in github,

So if you have any idea, or any post which help me to build a SaaS product, Help me

NOTE: My Stack:  Node + Express + Angular + Mysql or Postgres

My Question is How to use multiple schemas in postgres?

Comment: If you end up changing your mind about the querying, you should check into GraphQL, a simple query language for your API. https://graphql.org/

Comment: IMHO, you should go with option 3. We had the same situation. I blogged on why and how of it [here](https://medium.com/@adhasmana/how-we-implemented-multi-tenancy-in-our-node-js-app-cf9a2515969b)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i decided to use option 2, and i moved to Postgresql instead of mysql, because Postgresql has schema based approach!

Now my final code:

```
const postgresDB = new Sequelize('postgres://localhost:5432/test_enduser');

postgresDB.authenticate().then((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There is connection in ERROR.');
  } else {
    console.log('Postgres Connection has been established successfully');
  }
});

postgresDB.define('inventory', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const createSchema = () => {
  Business.findAll({
    raw: true,
  }).then((data) => {
    data.forEach((client) => {
      postgresDB.createSchema(client.code).then(() => {
        Object.keys(postgresDB.models).forEach((currentItem) => {
          postgresDB.models[currentItem].schema(client.code).sync();
        });
        // new schema is created
        console.log('Postgres schema created');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    });
  });
};
createSchema();


// apis
exports.getAllBusiness = (req, res) => {
  postgresDB.models.inventory.schema(req.user.code).findAll()
    .then((results) => {
      res.send(results);
    });
};

exports.postBusiness = (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    name: req.body.name,
  };
  postgresDB.models.inventory.schema(req.user.code).create(user)
    .then(data => res.status(200).send(data))
    .catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, err => res.status(422).send(err.errors[0].message))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err.message));
};
```

I am setting my postgres connection

Simply for test i am creating a table called "inventory"

In my application a online came and he signup, while signup i am storing there Business Code into my Business table(The Business table coming from separate DB, which is a super main app DB), so i am finding the business code and looping and make dynamic schemas in postgres

Now see my api, I am doing CRUD based on req.user.code(from login session),and i am finally matching showing datas according to particular schemas,

So finally i have clean separate schemas for each client

Thanks!